# php spl_autoload not working from other directory

Tags: php

this is my index.php file in project root:

```
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();
```

I added this into htaccess in order to redirect everything into public folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Inside public folder I just included index file like so:

```
// public/index.php file
require '../index.php';
```

But it's throwing an error:

```
Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class controllers\TestController could not be loaded
```

Why? If I remove htaccess and not use public folder it works perfectly.